# не удалось найти npmcli/config

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Захотел посмотреть react, на винде все нормально работает когда прописываю команду создания rect проекта, но на линуксе(mint 21) эта команды выкидывает:

```
  enter code herenode:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js:33:5)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js'
  ]
 }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо сделать, а то я js очень слабо знаю